# Box.Net API v2.0 Moving File on Service Action

Tags: box-api

Building a workflow that allows a file to be dynamically moved via user input (renames, the whole works). Using the Service Action, a web service will rename and move the file based on user input fields and some other behind the scenes processing. However, once the service runs and the window closes, the file is move but the user experience goes bad. The file keeps refreshing in the preview pane, redirects back to the root, and nothing works right until you navigate away.

The ideal solution would be the for the file to be moved and the user moved to the next file in the folder (or at minimum kept in the folder) as we're looking at a "processing" folder.

Is there any ideal best practice? Do I simply just need to copy the file instead of move and then run a delete routine after-the-fact?

Answer (score 0):

It may be best for you to contact Box via email at API at Box dot com to explain better what your application is trying to accomplish.  Generally describing the business case helps us resolve questions like this more quickly.